# How do I go through the calculation of evaluating an infinite integral using an contour with singularities on the real axis?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I have some integral like $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-1)} $$ This is going to have two singularities  on the real axis. So if you want to calculate this using the residue theorem with a semi-circle, then conceptually it makes sense to me that you'd make another inner semi-circle around each singularity and somehow have those inner radii go to 0 as the radius of the larger semi-circle goes to infinity. But what I don't know is how to actually go through that process of including those inner semi-circles to compute a number. How do I make one radius decrease as the other increases at the same time?

Comment: Maybe a keyhole contour, or if the integrand is symmetric integrate over the whole real line, and apply Cauchys integral theorem or the residue theorem, also consider splitting into partial fractions first. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration

Comment: Consider integrating the function $\frac1{z^2-1}$ over a semicircle with radius $R$ greater than or equal to $1$ (Using residue theorem/ integral formula). Now make $R\to\infty$ so that the actual improper integral is approximated.

Comment: Your integral diverges with principal value $0$. Partial fractions is enough for this

Comment: @Azlif isn’t the principal value $\pi i$?